# Reading values (of different shapes) from a file, that will be used for calculating certain area

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a file shapes.txt that has the following data:

```
Circle:15;
Rectangle:5,8;
Triangle:4,10,10;
```

In my Java program, I have an interface Shapes and I should use it for the calculation of the area of each shape (the interface contains one method `calcArea()`). I should read the file, and then create an array of objects and invoke the method calcArea for each object, so that it will calculate the areas (polymorphism).

I didn't know how to achieve that, so, this is the code I have written for reading the data from the file (I think it's not a good practice...):

```
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(loc)));
String line = in.readLine();
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(line);
String s1 = buf.substring(buf.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);

if (line.contains("Circle")) {
    Circle circle = new Circle(Integer.parseInt(s1));
}
```

For the Rectangle:

```
else if (line.contains("Rectangle")) {
     String[] a = ((line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(":") + 1)).split(","));
     int arf = Integer.parseInt(a[0]);
     int ars = Integer.parseInt(a[1]);
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(arf, ars);
}
```

Maybe I need to create a different method that will return an object of type Shapes, but if I start that way I don't know how to read the values from the file, so that I'll give them to the constructor of each object of type Shapes.

I would be grateful for any given opinions and help.

Comment: Not your down-voter, but what problems are you having with your code? Does it work? If so, go with it

Comment: I am not using polymorphism, and I don't have any ideas how to implement that in my code. This is my homework task, I need to use polymorphism...

Comment: i showed for `Circle` class, it is almost same for `Rectangle` and `Triangle` if you stuck i will help you @Cassara

Comment: Thank you but I need to use polymorphism... I need a method to return an object, and to create an array of those objects. These are the tips I have for solving this, bit I don't know how that can be done

Comment: `polymorphism` is okay, but `I need a method to return an object, and to create an array of those objects` what this method has to do, and what parametres it has to take, what it should return? this is not clear

Comment: As I understood, it should classificate the shapes (for example, if there is just one value read from the file, than the shape is a Circle), so the method should return an object of type Circle. It's not very clear to me too, to be honest...

Comment: i know what you are looking for, but it's better for you to understand the requirement clearly @Cassara